# How to make a separable Menu in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for my menu in bootstrap, which is separated by a line, but I would like to do a separated menu like the second image, with specific color and specific classification, is it possible to do this? I am just using `Bootstrap` and `jQuery`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">VOLVER</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #5</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accion #6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Accion #7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accion #8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accion #9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accion #10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accion #11</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the example that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVnkk.png)

[Here is the example that I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6tpE.jpg)

Comment: It ofcourse can be done. Have you ever read of bootsrap documentation? If you have not, check this link as a starter : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-header&stacked=h